# Find a sequence that converges outside of $[0, 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

The question says to show that in the Euclidean Metric Space $\mathbb{R}$, to prove that the set $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n$ is not closed such that $G_n = [0, \frac{n}{n+1}]$.

 I started out by listing the elements of $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n$ and showing that it was equal to the interval $[0, 1)$, but to show that it isn't closed, I need to find a sequence in $[0, 1)$ such that is converges to a point $p$ and $p \notin [0, 1)$. And then I started just randomly defining sequences and trying them out but I realized that that won't get me anywhere so that's why I asked this question. How can I find that sequence?

Comment: What about $\frac{n}{n+1}$? Its limit is $1$, but $1$ is not contained in any $G_n$ and thus not in the union.

Comment: If your final aim is to just show thatv$[0,1)$ is not closed then consider a deleted nbd at $1$ with radius $r$ and observe that it intersects with $[0,1)$ for each $r>0$ and conclude that $1$ is accumulation point of the set which is not in the set.